# Derivative for a piecewise defined function and continue its definition.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$
  f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    2e^{-x}-1, & \text{for } x \leq 0 \\
    x^2+1, & \text{for } 0 < x < 2 \\
    x^3-3, & \text{for } x \geq 2
  \end{cases}
  \
$

a) Determine the set $D$ where f is differentiable and calculate its derivative $f'$.

b) Is it possible to continue f with another condition so that it is still a"partially continuous function"?

---

For a) my answer would be:

$D = \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0,2\}$

$
  f'(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    -2e^{-x}, & \text{for } x < 0 \\
    2x, & \text{for } 0 < x < 2 \\
    3x^2, & \text{for } x > 2
  \end{cases}
  \
$

For b) if I add on another function, then $D$ would change since the transition point would still be in $D$. But there wouldn't exist a derivative in that transition point.

So if I would add the condition:" $for$ $x \geq 3: f(x) = x^2+15$"

In the point (3/24) I can't determine a derivate, so for the derivative the condition would then have to be: "$for$  $x >3$"

So does that mean that it is only possible if I change my set $D$ or is there another way?

Comment: It seems you have the correct idea. Part (b) seems ill-posed, I would like to see the book or lecture notes upon which this is based.

Comment: This is the original question in german: 
b) Ist es möglich $f'$ auf $\mathbb{R}$ stückweise stetig fortzusetzen? Falls ja, geben Sie eine stückweise stetige Fortsetzung an.

The important part is "stückweise stetig", in english I get something about regulated functions.

Comment: Thank you for the translation. Probably 'piecewise continuous'? I say, not knowing German